# Foreach loop inside of a case

Tags: php

I have been trying to get into PHP slugs and I encountered an issue - I'm trying to set up a way that I can just add a new entry in the array and it will make a new page for someone to be able to access.

This is the code:

```
 switch ($page) {

 // Adds the links.
 foreach ($LINKS as $linkName => $linkAdd) {
   case $linkName:
     require "templates/views/$linkAdd";
 }

 // The default switch.
 default:
   echo '404 Not Found';
 break;

 }
```

The loop gives me an error saying that it was unexpected to use a `foreach` loop inside of a `switch`, I was wondering if there was a way around this or if it's just smarted to not be using this method?

Is it only the `foreach` loop that is effected by this method? Or are there other types of loops for this.

Comment: you can use if-else instead of switch statement.

Comment: Yeah I added that as I was waiting for an answer :P Ill still wait though, I just cant support a 404 redirect unless there's a default: @akshaykhale

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foreach` cannot be used that way. And for your code, no need for that loop. This could be much simpler. You have `$Links` array with `$page` as the key and the values to used to include files.

```
if(isset($LINKS[$page])) { // check if $page exists in $LINKS
    require "templates/views/" . $LINKS[$page]; // include
} else {
    echo '404 Not Found'; // default case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the foreach loop directly after the switch, it must be inside a case-Statement (or default).

In this case, using a foreach is the wrong method, try using array_key_exists() instead:

```
if (!array_key_exists($page, $LINKS)) {
    // Default case
    echo '404 Not Found';
    exit;
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/templates/views' . $LINKS[$page];
```

A few other suggestions:

- Use single quotes instead of double quotes and use concetation.
- Always use absolute pathes (e.g. with `__DIR__`).
- Always use an explicit whitelist when including files (I just hope your $LINKS array is not created dynamically).

Comment: `$page` is the index. `array_key_exists` would work in this case.